# Querying a Master Detail Relationship

Tags: soql, master-detail

I am  currently learning Salesforce and Apex etc and I am stuck trying to write a trigger which contains a query.
Here are my two custom objects:

```
Student__c (Object)
Nickname__c
Email__c
Application__c:Master Detail Relationship


Application__c related to App__c

App__c (Object)
Name
```

So, now I want to write a query that fetches the pairs of (Email__c and the correct App__c.Name which is related to the student). So far I have

```
Select Email__c, Name FROM Student__c, App__c WHERE Application__r.Name = App__c.Name
```

This is not working, but I cannot quite get my head round querying a Master Detail Relationship. I am sure it's super simple and there is just one little thing I am missing.

Comment: Just to be sure - App__c is master-side in this relationship?

Comment: yes App__c is the master side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you just want do something like this?

```
Student__c student = [Select Email__c, Name, Application__r.Name 
                      FROM Student__c];
System.debug(student.Application__r.Name + '   =>  ' + student.Email__c);
```

This will return you Application Name and Student eMail.

BTW : In SOQL you can't compare 2 fields :(

Check this if you want start your work with salesforce SOQL:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm